# What is "toothless country"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In the movie *The Longest Yard*, there is a scene where players enter a football field, and a sports anchor says on TV:

> We are here deep in the heart of **toothless country**, coming to you from a simple Texas high school stadium that's been retrofitted for the big event.

I found a clip [here](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/4a79a9c5-f12d-4c7f-8d42-f7ac2bc0fcaf). What does *toothless country* mean here? Why would country be toothless?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a stereotype of country people. They're characterized as unsophisticated, often missing teeth. It's supposed to be a joke. The speaker is saying that they are in the middle of area of unsophisticated, rural people. For one example, think of [Cletus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cletus_Spuckler), from the Simpsons.

[image]